# Remove non-ascii and special characters from a string Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need help with a code
I want to remove non-ascii and special characters from a string.

```
   s = "Bjørn 10.2.3"
```

And I want it so that the output would remove special characters and non-ascii characteres.

like so,

```
  >>> Bjrn 1023
```

I'm aware of how to do it when it's only non-ascii or special characters.. not sure how it's done when it's both

What I have so far

For special characters

```
s = re.sub("[\"\'.]", "", special_character_string)
```

And For Non Ascii

```
encode = non_ascii_string.encode("ascii", "ignore")
        
    s = encode.decode()
```

Comment: Hi, what have you tried so far ?

Comment: I made an edit so it's easier to understand :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using simple Regex and `.replace()` -

```
import re

my_string = "Bjørn 10.2.3"
new_string = re.sub('[^A-z0-9 -]', '', my_string).replace(" ", " ")
print (new_string)
```

Output:

```
Bjrn 1023
```

Comment: @PebleJackson I'm glad it helped!! You can upvote both the answers as you now have the reputation to do so (click on the 'up' arrow beside each answer) .. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I mean it all comes down to which characters you want to remove, but the more important thing to focus on is the algorithm. A solution to your problem could be to iterate down your string and validate that each letter is considered "valid", by comparing each character to a list of valid characters.

```py
# Make a list of all your valid letters
valids = ["a", "b", "c" ... ]

# Iterate for each character in your string
final_string = ""
original_string = "Bjørn 10.2.3"
for character in list(original_string):
    # If the character is not valid
    if character in valids:
        final_string += character

# Your final string contains only your valid characters
print(final_string)
```

Comment: Is it possible to make an alphabetical list without typing it out? like by import string maybe?

Comment: Yes, you can use `from string import ascii_letters` to import the capitalized and uncapitalized English alphabet. If you would like to also include numbers, then concatenate it with `"1234567890"`. If the answer above helps you or works, then make sure to click the checkmark on the left of it to mark it as valid.

Comment: goodness this is a lot of code for a fairly simple task. seems way too complicated. i'm not a star-struck fan of regex, but it does fit the OP's question a lot better.